# Get first DateTime by given weekdays and a starttime

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime, linq

At work there is an input-system where customers are able to specify weekdays and a starting time for an event. The weekdays are integers in the range from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday).
After the customer has given the needed input, I need to calculate the next possible `DateTime` for the event. If the event is on the same day as today and the current time is not yet over the submitted starting-time, the next possible `DateTime` would be today.

This is what I have came up with, but it looks awful and complicated. You can obviously shorten the linq-queries a little, but i let the intermediate objects in there for sake of debugging.

```
public static class Test
{ 
    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var startTimes = new List<TimeSpan> {
            now.TimeOfDay ,                                     // get the next possible starting point
            now.TimeOfDay.Add( new TimeSpan( 0 , 1 , 0 ) ) ,    // starting point is today
        };
        var weekdaysList = new List<int[]> {
            new [] { 1 , 4 , 5 } ,
            new [] { 1 , 2 } ,
        };

        foreach( var weekdays in weekdaysList )
        {
            foreach( var startTime in startTimes )
            {
                var dt = GetNext( weekdays , startTime );
            }
        }
    }

    public static DateTime GetNext( int[] weekdays , TimeSpan startTime )
    {
        // convert to german format (Monday:1 - Sunday:7)
        var currentWeekDay = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

        if( currentWeekDay == 0 )
            currentWeekDay = 7;

        // if today, and not yet passed, return todays starting time
        if( weekdays.Contains( currentWeekDay ) )
        {
            var today = DateTime.Now.Date.Add( startTime );

            if( DateTime.Now < today )
                return today;
        }

        // calculate the day index and keep the added days around (better debugging)
        var days = Enumerable.Range( 0 , 7 )
            .Select( addedDays => new { addedDays , dayIndex = ( currentWeekDay + addedDays ) % 7 } )
            .ToArray();
        // only days that are specified
        var validDays = days
            .Where( x => weekdays.Contains( x.dayIndex ) )
            .ToArray();
        // the first day is the one that has the least days added
        var daysToAdd = validDays.First().addedDays;
        // but we already sorted out today, so the next possible day is the second (if exists) or 1 week/ 7 days later
        if( daysToAdd == 0 )
        {
            if( validDays.Count() > 1 )
                daysToAdd = validDays.ElementAt( 1 ).addedDays;
            else
                daysToAdd = 7;
        }

        return DateTime.Now.Date
            .AddDays( daysToAdd )
            .Add( startTime );
    }
}
```

I feel like I am missing some obvious shortcuts or linq-fu to shorten this code down and make it easier understandable.

I let this code as it is, but it was bugging me the whole day, how could I improve this?

<sub>Only the basic *algorithm* in the `GetNext()`-Method is relevant, no error-checking etc.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

After some fresh air I think I got around my mental blockade. I simply convert to the natural C# `DayOfWeek` representation beforehand instead of fiddling around with the other one.

```
public static IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> ConvertDaysOfWeek( int[] daysOfWeekIds )
    => daysOfWeekIds.Select( x => x == 7 ? DayOfWeek.Sunday : (DayOfWeek)x );

public static DateTime GetNext( IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek , TimeSpan startTime )
{
    var nextDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    var isToday = daysOfWeek.Contains( nextDate.DayOfWeek ) && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < startTime;

    if( !isToday )
        nextDate = Enumerable.Range( 1 , 7 )
            .Select( x => nextDate.AddDays( x ) )
            .First( x => daysOfWeek.Contains( x.DayOfWeek ) );

    return nextDate.Add( startTime );
}
```

Comment: In the `ConvertDaysOfWeek` method, couldn't you just take mod 7 of x and convert? That way 7 would be 0 and the other values would remain the same. It would save you having to code a special check for value 7.

Answer (score 0):

I made some suggestions for your code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //input samples
    var startTimes = new List<TimeSpan> { DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, DateTime.Now.AddHours(4).TimeOfDay };
    var weekdaysList = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 5, 2 }; //why did you choose make it a list of integer arrays?, if thats how its populated, you could later flatten it

    //you'll want to sort the lists for convenience
    startTimes.Sort();
    weekdaysList.Sort();

    var next_event = GetNext(weekdaysList, startTimes);
}
public static DateTime GetNext(List<int> daysOfWeekIds, List<TimeSpan> startTimes)
{
    var today = DateTime.Now;
    var today_Day = (int)today.DayOfWeek;
    var today_Time = today.TimeOfDay;

    TimeSpan later_that_day = startTimes.Where(st => st > today_Time).FirstOrDefault() - today_Time;

    //check if day is the same at a later time
    if (daysOfWeekIds.Any(d => (d == today_Day)) && later_that_day.TotalMinutes > 0) //you may want to put a minimum time threshold here for same-day events
    {
        return today.Add(later_that_day);
    }

    //check if it can be done later in the same week
    int later_that_week = daysOfWeekIds.Where(d => d > today_Day).FirstOrDefault() - today_Day;

    if (later_that_week > 0)
    {
        return today.AddDays(later_that_week).Add(later_that_day);
    }

    //pick the earliest date for next week
    return today.AddDays(7 - today_Day).AddDays(daysOfWeekIds.FirstOrDefault()).Add(later_that_day);
}
```